# CSS div not moving to the middle

Tags: html, css

I am making my own website, but for some reason I can't move the black box into the middle of the screen please could you guys help me out. I have to make it on JSFiddle because I don't have enough RP to show screenshots on here.

Please see this link to view my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/LfWBn/4/

```
#white_box {
position:absolute;
margin:auto 0;
min-width:80%;
max-width:100%;
height:85%;
top:0%;
background:black;
z-index:1;
width:80%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you have `fixed width` always to 80% or will be dynamic between 80 and 100? http://jsfiddle.net/LfWBn/7/

Comment: Thanks Danko it worked! (would thumbs up but I'm only on 8 RP :( but thanks)

Comment: Np mate glad to help you I post that as the answer after 15 minutes you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: Don't worry just realised haha will do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `width` is always `80%` then just offset the left half of the restant width:

```
left:10%;
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/LfWBn/7/

Comment: correct, no hack needed here. your box is 80% of the container, which means there's 20% left over. if you want the box centered in the container, you want that 20% to be shown equally on the left and right, i.e. `left:10%`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work:

```
#white_box {
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto 0;
        min-width:80%;
        max-width:100%;
        height:85%;
        top:7%;
        left:10%;
        background:black;
        z-index:1;
        width:80%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the margin on auto, try it out: margin: 20px;